# Java fx-8. How to configure path to local image using fxml file

Tags: image, url, javafx

I have some troubles configuring path to local image in my javaFX application.
I want to use icon to my button, but it's not working for local images, only with external resources. This is my code:

```
            <Button fx:id="magicWangButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#magicWang" text="Magic wang">
                <graphic>
                    <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="20.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
                        <image>
                            <!--<Image url="/fxml/img/magic-wang.png" />-->

                            <Image url="https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1evM.png" />
                            <!--<Image url="/fxml/img/site-logo.png" />-->
                            <Image url="img/magic-wang.png"/>
                        </image>
                    </ImageView>
                </graphic>
            </Button>
```

this string work's fine:

```
<Image url="https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1evM.png" />
```

, but others...
My image located in path: resources/fxml/img/
all fxml files located in fxml directory.
I saw other questions and answers but it uses configuration in java files, but it is not what I looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to start the url with "@" and call [FXMLLoader.setLocation()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setLocation-java.net.URL-).

- relative URLs:

  - @one24.png:
  - @image/two24.png
  - @../three24.png
- absolute URLs:

  - @/four24.png
  - @/image/five24.png

Please note that I've implemented a utility class: [FXMLLoaders](http://www.drombler.org/drombler-commons/0.13/docs/site/apidocs/org/drombler/commons/fx/fxml/FXMLLoaders.html)

If you stick to the following naming conventions:

- MyComponent.java
- MyComponent.fxml (same package as MyComponent.java)
- MyComponent.properties (same package as MyComponent.java)

you can use the following code:

**For fx:root based FXML files:**

```
public MyComponent() {
    FXMLLoaders.loadRoot(this);
}
```

**Otherwise:**

```
Parent root = FXMLLoaders.load(FxmlSampleApplication.class);
```

The library is available from Maven Central:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drombler.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>drombler-commons-fx-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.13</version>
</dependency>
```

You can find a full sample which loads images on [GitHub](https://github.com/Drombler/drombler-commons/tree/develop/drombler-commons-fx/drombler-commons-fx-samples/drombler-commons-fx-samples-core).

I've also written a [blog post](https://puces-blog.blogspot.com/2015/03/drombler-commons-conventions-to.html) about this utility class and the naming conventions.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a path relative to the fxml by starting the attribute value with `@`, see [*Introduction to FXML: Location Resolution*](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#location_resolution)

```xml
<Image url="@img/site-logo.png" />
```